# C/Linux: How to get users login name without `getlogin`

Tags: c, linux

I need to retrieve the users username in a C program. I know about `getlogin` and `getlogin_r`. But my program has a redirected stdin (because of some `forks`).

The Problem I face is stated in the manpage:

> Note that glibc does not follow the POSIX specification and uses stdin
>   instead of /dev/tty.  A bug.  (Other recent systems, like SunOS 5.8
>   and HP-UX 11.11 and FreeBSD 4.8 all return the login name also when
>   stdin is redirected).

Is there any other way I could retrieve the username?

Comment: Depending on what you want to use it for, `getenv()` and `$USER` spring to mind... not really reliable, but...

Comment: What do you need to user name for? The answer could depend on that.

Comment: For showing it in a gui and transmitting it via network. It should be reliable

Comment: That paragraph can be obsolete, and the non-posix technique used by glibc be incorrect nowadays. hp-ux 11.11 is an old version and FreeBSD 4.8 a very old one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [getresuid(2)](https://www.linux.com/manpage/man2/getresgid.2.html) or some of the more specific id retrieval functions to get the id you want (real, effective, or saved-set) (you probably want RUID, if you want to emulate `getlogin`, in which case you can simply call `getuid` and forget about the effective and saved-set uid), and then use [getpwuid(3)](https://www.linux.com/manpage/man3/getpwuid.3.html) or its reentrant counterpart to translate that to a user id string.

`getenv("USER")` might give you the same result, but you can't rely on it if you want real security.

Technically, all these may be different from the result obtained by `getlogin` when stdin is your controlling terminal. If you really need the same answer as what `getlogin` would get you, you can temporarily make your fd 0 point to your controlling terminal again, then call `getlogin`, and then restore your fd 0:

```
int saved_fd0;
if(0>(saved_fd0 = dup(0))
       /*handle error*/;
close(0);

/*open always gets the lowest possible fd number == now 0*/
/*"/dev/tty" is always your current processes's controlling terminal*/
if(0>open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY))
    /*handle error*/;
/*
getlogin()
..
*/
/*restore saved_fd0*/
if(0>dup2(saved_fd0, 0))
       /*handle error*/;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the id user with [getuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) and then call [getpwuid_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) to find out the username the corresponds to that id.

**Edit**: Oops, I meant to say [getpwuid_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) instead of [getpwent_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent_r.3.html) as correctly @PSkocik pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with possible mis-identifications (multiple logins tied to the same UID), you can use `getuid(2)` or `getresuid(2)` to get the UID, then use `getpwuid(3)` to get the name (or, in the case of multiple usernames with the same UID, one of the names, the documentation is not clear on if this is a random name, the first encountered in the file, ...).

This does not rely on any specific file descriptor pointing at the logged-in terminal, nor does it rely on utmp records, but it does rely on the UID being present in /etc/passwd and MAY not identify the correct login name used, in the presence of multiple logins tied to the same UID (although that should be infrequent enough to not be an actual concern).