# Reduce memory allocations, using getlogin()

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In my simple terminal shell `getlogin()` causes 13 memory allocation every loop , checked before and after with `valgrind`.

The allocations are properly handled , there is no problem to be solved, but i am just having fun trying to reduce the allocations of my program and learning stuff along the way.

Is there a way to reduce allocations caused by `getlogin()`?

Already tried :

- [Use getuid and then call getpwuid_r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292636/c-linux-how-to-get-users-login-name-without-getlogin)
- `getlogin_r`

Comment: Look at the source of `getlogin` and implement it in a way that doesn't allocate as much. The same stands for any library function.

Comment: Call it once instead of every loop?

Comment: Apparently getlogin isn't a very good or reliable function, anyway. What do you need it for?

Comment: I am building a shell for an assignment, so i need it every loop  for now ,maybe later i can check only at the start of the shell? I mean where else is the user changing?

Comment: Normally, a shell is started after the login, so the user does not change. I suggest to call `getlogin` once and save the returned pointer. Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you want to achieve by calling `getlogin`. According to the "BUGS" section of the [`getlogin` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin) there might be better alternatives.